# How do I stop play bar jitteryness in jPlayer?

Tags: jplayer

I'm having some issues with my play bar being super jittery on a site's implementation.

Getting this thing functioning and styled the same in a jsfiddle, so I have to apologize for not having one.

The example is here: http://mindevo.com/geewhiz/music-tracks.html

When you start playing the seek bar bounces very jittery and continues to do so the entire time.

How can I prevent this jitteryness?

Here is my initialize function (this page is actually a fall-back for the real AJAX-loaded page which resides on http://mindevo.com/geewhiz/ ) and for now includes only the example tracks for jplayer.

```
    function startPlaylist() {
    new jPlayerPlaylist({
        jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
    }, [
            {
                title:"Cro Magnon Man",
                mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.mp3"
            },
            {
            title:"Your Face",
            mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-05-Your_face.mp3"
            },
            {
                title:"Cyber Sonnet",
                mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-07-Cybersonnet.mp3"
            },
            {
                title:"Tempered Song",
                mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-01-Tempered-song.mp3"
            },
            {
                title:"Song 5 Song",
                mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-01-Tempered-song.mp3"
            },
            {
                title:"8 Song",
                mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-01-Tempered-song.mp3"
            }
        ], {
            swfPath: "../../dist/jplayer",
            loopOnPrevious: true,
            supplied: "mp3",
            loop: true,
            wmode: "window",
            useStateClassSkin: true,
            autoBlur: false,
            smoothPlayBar: true,
            keyEnabled: true,
            preload: "auto"
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. I tried your suggestion of setting it to false, but this disables the smooth transitions.  It's better than having the jitteriness, but would prefer to fix it and still have smooth transitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, setting "smoothPlayBar: false" solves this problem.

I am leaving this here for anyone else experiencing a jittery play-bar.